# UITapGestureRecognizer Error, when I add to an imageview

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, event-handling, action

I use UITapGestureRecognizer to handle An ImageviewTap actions. In the main ViewController it works great. But when i Use another ViewController in my APP, and copy the same UITapRecognizer code I get an EXC_BAD_ACCESS code=1 address: 0x80759d3a error message to the line when i add the recognizer to my imageview. What do I wrong?

My ImageView: It works

```
UIImageView *live;
live = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(92, 230, 136, 100)];
live.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"online.png"];
[live addSubview:onlineLabel2];
[live setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
[self.view addSubview:live];
[super viewDidLoad];
```

and my Gesture Recognizer:

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *singleTaP3 = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(onlineTap:)];
singleTaP3.numberOfTapsRequired = 1;
singleTaP3.numberOfTouchesRequired = 1;    
[live addGestureRecognizer:singleTaP3];
```

and the last line i get the crash.

Comment: First, you should call [super viewDidLoad]; first and after that add the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem was in my main viewcontroller. I called the new viewcontroller wrong, and get nullpointer for it. Get it in property, and it works. The problem is not with gesturetaprecognizer.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like your live view is not retain, so when you try to add the gesture, the view doesn't exist anymore. Try to record your live view as a property in your interface, and synthetise it in your implementation.

Comment: Could you please give us your -(void)viewDidLoad method and your interface ?

Comment: Before assigning _live you are declaring a local var live which is overwriting your property live.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/4Zt64WCh
Here is my code! I copied it to my main viewcontroller, and there works fine.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if that this causing you to crash your code but you should call

```
[super viewDidLoad];
```

at the start of the code. (If you are using ARC than this looks fine.)

```
[super viewDidLoad]; 
UIImageView *live;
live = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(92, 230, 136, 100)];
live.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"online.png"];
[live addSubview:onlineLabel2];
[live setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
[self.view addSubview:live];
```

Comment: If you use ARC you should declare your property like this (strong, not retain):@property (nonatomic, strong) UIImageView *live;

Comment: I set to property @property (nonatomic, strong) UIImageView *live;
and add gesturerecognizer to _live, same error

Answer (score 0):

I test the following and it works.
The interface:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface ViewController : UIViewController

@property (strong, nonatomic) UIView *v;

- (void)tapAction;

@end
```

And the implementation:

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@implementation ViewController

@synthesize v=_v;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    _v = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 10, 50, 50)];
    [_v setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];

    [self.view addSubview:_v];

    UITapGestureRecognizer *tap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(tapAction)];
    tap.numberOfTouchesRequired = 1;
    tap.numberOfTapsRequired = 1;

    [_v addGestureRecognizer:tap];
}

- (void)tapAction
{
    NSLog(@"tap tap");
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@end
```